# Unable to get last entry from SQL Server Compact Edition Database Through Group By And Order By Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact database with two tables:

1. Consumers
2. Monthly Bills

Each month's bill is stored in the monthly bill table, I want to get consumers with the last month bill stored in the monthly bill table. I have tried the following query, but I'm not getting the expected result.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    CM.id,
    MM.BillMonth,
    SUM(MM.AfterDuePayable) AS AfterDuePayable 
FROM
    MonthlyBills MM 
LEFT JOIN
    Cosumers CM ON MM.ConsumerCode = CM.id 
WHERE
    CM.isActive = 0 
    AND MM.AfterDuePayable > 0 
GROUP BY 
    CM.id, MM.BillMonth 
ORDER BY
    CM.id,
    DATEPART(Month, MM.BillMonth),
    DATEPART(Year, MM.BillMonth) DESC
```

Tables:

[Database Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ5ir.png)

This is the result I get:

```
ID      BillMonth     AfterDuePayable
--------------------------------------
30      2023-01-02          5710
```

Expected result is:

```
ID      BillMonth     AfterDuePayable
-------------------------------------
1       2023-01-02      400
2       2023-05-06      350
3       2022-05-08      340
```

Comment: I see nothing at all to do with C# or VB.NET in this question. It appears to be purely a SQL question. Please don't tag a question with your application language unless it's relevant to the question. Also, a question pretty much can't be specific to C# and VB. If the application language is relevant, specify THE application language.

Comment: Also, SQL Server CE and SQL Server are two different things, despite the similarity in names.

Comment: You have top 1 so should only get 1 row returned, And please publish sample data as text.

Comment: Hello, Dear Thank you for your Comment, I want to get only the Last Month's Record of Each Consumer, that's why I have the top 1 in the query.

Comment: that is not how TOP 1 work, it will only get the first row from your entire select

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: 'TOP (expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES ]
Indicates that only a specified first set or percent of rows will be returned from the query result set' - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Hello, Thanks to, All the Respected comments. I haven't achieved my goal. I have a database table with each month's electricity bill of consumers. some of the consumers haven't paid their electricity bills. I want to get the last not-paid invoice of each consumer. the electricity bill information is stored month vice in the database. i have tried the above query and can not get my required result. kindly study the query and guide me how can I get my required result.

Thank you